# IntegrityError at non-existing field

Tags: python, database, django

I'm having troubles with adding new copy of existing model Clients, which looks like:

```
class Client(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User) # Extending default user model
  organization = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name
```

Im entering shell and type this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from mysiteApp.models import Client

user = User.objects.get(pk=2) # User with pk 2 exists
client = Client(user=user, organization="someorg") # copy creates succesfully
```

But then, im trying to save copy by
client.save()

And im getting this:

```
>>> client.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 537, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 641, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 215, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1559, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 844, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 41, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 389, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 387, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: mysiteApp_client.cID may not be NULL
```

The thing is that i HAD such field as cID in Client model before, wich really had NOT NULL, but now i dont

manage.py sql mysiteApp shows:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "mysiteApp_client" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
    "organization" varchar(40) NOT NULL
)
;
```

manage.py syncdb changes nothing, what should i do? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database is still in the state as where the cID field is required. This is because [syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) does not alter already existing tables.

To overcome your problem you have three options:

a) delete the Client table (=lose your data) in your database and run `syncdb` again

b) manually modifying your database using a sql `ALTER TABLE` command

c) use a migration tool like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) ([introduction](http://www.djangopro.com/2011/01/django-database-migration-tool-south-explained/)) to reflect the changes you did for models.py in your database. I would recommend to learn how to deal with South, as once you are in production you probably need such a migration tool.

Comment: Removing and recreating table solved the problem, thanks alot.